# EKS Ingress without Address - Trying to test my EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm having a small issue that's been taking so much time without luck.

I have an EKS cluster where I created 2 deployments each with it's own service.

My 2 apps are a tensorflow server and a flask app which runs queries on the tf server using the IP of the service dedicated to it.

Now I want to access the Flask app running on one of the 2 from the outside world. So I created an Ingress but it shows with no address at all when I try "kubectl get ingress".

```
NAME          HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
nlp-ingress   *                 80      4h5m
```

I have also noticed the following in the logs of the Flask container

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 343-385-569
192.168.14.156 - - [16/Jul/2020 17:13:24] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00{\x01\x00\x00w\x03\x03')
192.168.14.156 - - [16/Jul/2020 17:13:24] "[35m[1m\00{\00\00w[0m" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
192.168.14.156 - - [16/Jul/2020 17:13:24] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
192.168.14.156 - - [16/Jul/2020 17:13:24] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

My ingress yaml file is the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nlp-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nlp-client-service
    servicePort: 5000
```

The yaml of my Flask deployment and service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nlp-client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: nlp-client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nlp-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nlp-client-container
        image: myimage:latest
        command:
          - "python"
          - "main.py"
          - "--server"
          - "nlp-server-service:8501"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nlp-client-service
  name: nlp-client-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: nlp-client
  type: LoadBalancer
```

My aim is to test my cluster during development.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ingress to work , you need an ingress controller like [one of these](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers). The most common one is the [Nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Now if you are running both applications on the same cluster, you don't even need an Ingress on your TF server , a plain [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) on port `5000` would do, assuming that's the port where your [TF server is listening on](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving).

If you still want to use an Ingress you can still use it but the path would be kind of odd, meaning the request will how out of the cluster and then back into the cluster.

Comment: Thank you @Rico, I actually have one service that I exposed and indeed I can test the Flask app now. However, the TF server seems to be acting weird even if in the logs it shows the grpc server is working fine. When I try a request either from the Flask app or from Postman, it seems to be simply timing out. I'll look more into it and possibly open a new question about that.